# Could I contain permission name in string res

Tags: android, permissions

Sample code:

```
<permission
    android:name="@string/permission_name"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>
```

Error while building: missing name attribute in element .

But I don't want to duplicate permission name in my different applications.
Is exist some way for fix it and contain permission in resources?

Answer (score 3):

No, that's impossible. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#nm). You can use resources to specify a label, but not the name:

> The name must be unique, so it should use Java-style scoping — for example, "com.example.project.PERMITTED_ACTION".