# "Missing name attribute" error when specifying permission name as resValue.

Tags: android, gradle, manifest

I have a couple of different Gradle buildTypes and am trying to specify the Google C2D_MESSAGE permission names individually for each of these buildTypes because I can't have the different apps installed on my phone because they share a permission name. But I'm running into a "Missing name attribute" error.

So I'm doing something like this in my build.gradle:

```
    buildType2 {
        applicationIdSuffix '.suffix1'
        ...
        resValue 'string', 'gcmPermission', "com.mypackage.suffix1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    }
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<permission
    android:name="@string/gcmPermission"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="@string/gcmPermission" />
```

However, I run into the following error when building:

```
AndroidManifest.xml:19: missing name attribute in element <permission>.
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045784/could-i-contain-permission-name-in-string-res), the problem is simply that the 'name' attribute cannot reference a string resource, it must be a raw string.

> You can use resources to specify a label, but not the name.
>
> The name must be unique, so it should use Java-style scoping — for example, "com.example.project.PERMITTED_ACTION".

This is why the solution provided by arne.jans works. The Gradle variable is substituted pre-compilation, appearing as a raw string to the Manifest.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by replacing the package-name in permission- and uses-permission elements with a placeholder which gets replaced by gradle automatically for buildtypes and/or productFlavors:

```
    <permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can define your own manifest placeholder in `build.gradle`:

```
buildType2 {
    manifestPlaceholders = [permissionName: 'com.example.my_perm']

    #You can define it also as a string resource here
    resValue 'string', 'permissionName',  'com.example.my_perm'
}
```

Then you can use `${permissionName}` in Android manifest or `R.string.permissionName` in your code.