# Defining permission in manifest from string file, android?

Tags: android, manifest

In my app I am using GCM for push notification, we have to set 2 permission tags in the manifest of whose value I am picking up from string xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="@string/app_gcm_permission" />

<permission
    android:name="@string/app_gcm_permission"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

In the string file

```
<string name="app_gcm_permission">com.lift.chi.permission.C2D_MESSAGE</string>
```

The gradle build is successful and when I try to run the app I get the below error

```
error: invalid Java identifier '@string/app_gcm_permission'.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: invalid Java identifier '@string/app_gcm_permission'
```

This is happening because android studio internally converts dot to underscore due to which it throws the invalid java identifier error.
Please don't give me solutions to add the permission directly in manifest rather than picking from string file.

How can I resolve this??

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045784/could-i-contain-permission-name-in-string-res

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it on the basis of answer on this question

[Set string from gradle in manefesst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954071/how-can-i-access-a-buildconfig-value-in-my-androidmanifest-xml-file?noredirect=1#comment90146079_40592469)

The solution code, in build gradle, ->android->defaultConfig

```
manifestPlaceholders = [ gcmPermission:"com.lift.chi.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"]
```

And in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="${gcmPermission}" />

<permission
    android:name="${gcmPermission}"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use string resource in `android:name` field of `<uses-permission>`. You will have to use predefined strings. For more details visit this link :-

[Manifest Permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element)

Comment: string resource can be used for permission

Comment: yeah but not in `android:name` field of `<uses-permission>`. Check out the link above

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a quick fix

```
 <permission
    android:name="com.lift.chi.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of

```
<uses-permission android:name="@string/app_gcm_permission" />

<permission
    android:name="@string/app_gcm_permission"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

do it

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.lift.chi.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.lift.chi.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```